# How to disable angular service worker for reactjs iframe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm using Angular 11 in main app and reactjs in iframe.

The problem is that the service worker from main Angular app tries to work for iframe reactjs app, causing all requests in iframe to fail with 403 error, including bundle/vendor request.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

How can I intercept all reqeusts made in react app, including vendor/bundle loading reqeusts? ( to set a bypass header for them )

According to Angular docs I need to set a bypass header for reqeusts https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker

Comment: So you are suggesting that if you run this app as a standard app and not a PWA with a service worker you _do not_ get a 403 from the iframe?

Comment: withour service worker there's no errors.

Comment: Angular service worker tries to proxy requests made in iframe, but I suppose browsers doesn't allow that, therefore it throws 403 forbidden errors

Comment: check the referrer header of the request from the iframe to ensure it is the same as the parent window.

Comment: it is the same.
main app url: "example/".
iframe url: "example/v2.1/"